# Get likes.size of all posts by user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, associations

Ok, `<%= @post.likes.size %>` is easy. But how to get likes of **all posts** created by user? `<%= @user.posts.likes.size %>` throws:

```
undefined method `likes' for #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy_Post:0x69c9198>
```

**models/user.rb**

```
has_many :likes, foreign_key: "liker_id", dependent: :destroy
has_many :liked_posts, through: :likes, source: :liked
```

**models/post.rb**

```
has_many :likes, foreign_key: "liked_id", dependent: :destroy
has_many :liker_users, through: :likes, source: :liker
```

**models/like.rb**

```
belongs_to :liker, class_name: "User"
belongs_to :liked, class_name: "Post", :counter_cache => :likes_count
validates :liker_id, presence: true
validates :liked_id, presence: true
```

Note, with the above models `<%= @user.likes.size %>` returns how many posts this user has liked, not the size of likes on his posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
@user.posts.joins(:likes).count
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Post.joins(:likes).where("likes.user_id = ?", user.id).count
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the low-level answers, the high level answer is...

```
User.has_many :posts
Post.has_many :likes
User.has_many :likes, through: :posts
```

That way, a mere `@user.likes.count` will add up a single user's entire fan club.

The low-level answers are good to know, and illustrate useful techniques. This answer is "better" insofar as it's DRY, and it minimizes `<% code %>` in the view. That's kind'a important!

Comment: I disagree. Setting up a full relationship between the models just gives you a slightly shorter syntax to count the records. Under the hood there's no benefit. If anything it just serves to complicate the models. Additionally, there's no need for the reverse association `Post.has_many :likes` unless you're going to use it.

Comment: Definitely valid point. I thought of that, but not sure how it would play out as `models/user.rb` already has `has_many :likes` which are the opposite: the likes user has given to posts.

Comment: That's why it's the "high level" answer. It's not automatically the "best" answer, just because it's "high level".